# Getting error 404 when using Webclient.DownloadData(myUrl) but myUrl exists

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to get response from this url but I get error 404 (not found) exception in c#.
The Code I'am using :

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";
    var myUrl = "this is a payment check url with query that i expect to get payment status";
    response = client.DownloadData(myUrl );//Exception error 404 throw here
}
```

One point : When I use myUrl in Internet Explorer 9 I get error 404 But When I try this on Chrome 56 it worked without any problem

Anybody know what's I have done wrong here?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: thats up to that web server, not your code here.

Answer (score 1):

Use either [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) or the Developer Tools trace tool to compare what is happening in each case.

The HTTP 404  says that you are reaching your server (actually, an HTTP server) but that you are requesting something that it doesn't have (or, for some reason may not want to give you). So you should also check to see if you are getting the same IP address in each case.

Comment: thanks for your answer.But as I said the url is reachable via chrome.If it doesn't exist why it work on chrome.On more thing . I test that url on my server via Javascript . It works fine but I don't know why it doesn't work on c# .

Comment: because IE might be trying to connect to the site through a proxy. That's why I suggested that you should check with Fiddler.